# How do you nest API calls in Angular 2?

Tags: angularjs, http, angular

I would like to get data from one Restful service and then use that data when getting data from another restful service.

The flow is basically

```
http.get("http://service.com/firstservice")
.onresponse(function(res){
     http.get("http://service.com/firstservice/" + res)
     .onresponse(function(res){
          console.log(res);
          // display in view
     }
}
)
```

How can this be done in Angular 2?

Answer (score 2):

You leverage the `flatMap` operator:

```
return http.get("http://service.com/firstservice")
    .map(res => res.json())
    .flatMap((data) => {
      return http.get("http://service.com/firstservice/" + res);
    })
    .map(res => res.json());
```

The `map` operator is necessary if you want to extract the JSON payload of responses.

Comment: Is there a more straightforward way?